# Nim varargs in template?

Tags: nim-lang

How do you use `varargs` in a template (I know that it's possible to do that with a macro, but I am wondering if it's also possible with a template too)? The example below doesn't compile

```
template require*(modules: varargs[untyped]) =
  for m in modules:
    from m import nil

require options, strutils
```

But this is working

```
template require*(a) =
  from a import nil
template require*(a, b) =
  from a import nil
  from b import nil

require options, strutils
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`varargs` DOES work in templates* but your use case requires a macro, a template is just code substitution and the following code is not valid nim code:

```
for m in [options, strutils]:
  from m import nil
```

*example of `varargs` usage in template:

```
template require(modules: varargs[untyped]) =
  import modules
  
require options, strutils
```